# android.net.VPNServicec is not an enclosing Class

Tags: java, android, xml, service, vpn

Trying to implement VPN following the android Docs and facing this problem

My Current Code

```
public class MyVpnService extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    VpnService.Builder builder = new VpnService.Builder();
    ParcelFileDescriptor localTunnel = builder
            .addAddress("192.168.2.2", 24)
            .addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0)
            .addDnsServer("192.168.1.1")
            .establish();

    String[] appPackages = {
            "com.android.chrome",
            "com.google.android.youtube",
            "com.example.a.missing.app"};

    VpnService.Builder builder = new VpnService.Builder();
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    for (String appPackage: appPackages) {
        try {
            packageManager.getPackageInfo(appPackage, 0);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                builder.addAllowedApplication(appPackage);
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            // The app isn't installed.
        }
    }
    localTunnel = builder
            .addAddress("2001:db8::1", 64)
            .addRoute("::", 0)
            .establish();
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<service android:name=".MyVpnService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.VpnService"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.net.VpnService.SUPPORTS_ALWAYS_ON"
            android:value="false"/>
</service>
```

There is a red Line under 
    VpnService.Builder builder = new VpnService.Builder();

The error reads

**android.net.VpnService is not an enclosing class**

Answer (score 1):

That's because `MyVpnService` extends `android.app.Service` and not `android.net.VpnService`, which it must do to act as VPN service.

Comment: i Replaced extends service to extends android.app.Service